# JButton not adding JLabel with an ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface

I've started working on an extension of a project I've been working on for a few months, and I've felt the need to take it out of the console and put in in a GUI window. So far everything's going great! Except one thing, When I try to test the Login button (It's just so I can limit who uses it, and to see if I could do it.) the action listener isn't responding like I hoped it would. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;


public class Main {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Main() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 612, 389);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("User name");
    lblUserName.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    lblUserName.setBounds(158, 70, 67, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUserName);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setBounds(158, 146, 53, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(235, 143, 118, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(235, 72, 118, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setBounds(151, 228, 256, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(textField.equals("Admin"))
            {
                if(textField.equals("Admin"))
                {
                    JLabel lblLoginSuccessPlease = new JLabel("LOGIN SUCCESS! Please wait while the other functions are loaded");
                    lblLoginSuccessPlease.setBounds(124, 204, 344, 14);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginSuccessPlease);

                }
            }

        }
    });      

    JLabel lblWelcomeToMy = new JLabel("Welcome to my amazing program!");
    lblWelcomeToMy.setBounds(174, 11, 242, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToMy);
    }
}
```

I've tried to use the && to test both the Username and the Password box, and it wouldn't work either. Also, if someone could instruct me on how to make the Password box have the characters masked that'd be extremely helpful.

Comment: I put this as a programming question in my mind... So I posted to the programming stack exchange.

Comment: It's not "programming", it's "programmers". Implementation questions are off topic here.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry then. Maybe, no I'll get an answer on stack overflow being it was migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `frame` has private access in `Main` class

   ```
   private JFrame frame;
   ```

   change it to public or remove the modifier
2. To get the text of JTextfield use [textfield.getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText())

   ```
     //if (textField.equals("Admin")) {wrong
           if (textField.getText().equals("Admin")) {//right way
   ```
3. You have to check the password not the username again

   ```
     if (textField_1.getText().equals("Admin")) {
             f (textField.getText().equals("Admin")) {//this is the password field
   ```
4. To mask the passwords you have to use [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html).so create like

   ```
   private JPasswordField textField;
   ```

   and initialize like

   ```
   textField = new JPasswordField();
   ```

   and check like

   ```
   if (textField_1.getText().equals("Admin")) {
               if (String.valueOf(textField.getPassword()).equals("Admin")) {
                   JLabel lblLoginSuccessPlease = new JLabel("LOGIN SUCCESS! Please wait while the other functions are loaded");
                   lblLoginSuccessPlease.setBounds(124, 204, 344, 14);
                   frame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginSuccessPlease);

               }
           }
   ```

Comment: thanks, I was using my window builder and noticed that right after I posted it and got mad at myself for not paying attention

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(textField.equals("Admin"))
        {
            if(textField.equals("Admin"))
            {
                JLabel lblLoginSuccessPlease = new JLabel("LOGIN SUCCESS! Please wait while the other functions are loaded");
                lblLoginSuccessPlease.setBounds(124, 204, 344, 14);
                frame.getContentPane().add(lblLoginSuccessPlease);

            }
        }
```

First of all, no need to check if textField is equal to "Admin" twice.

But the main problem is that a text field, which is a white rectangle accepting input in a UI, is ever equal to a String, which is a sequence of characters.

What you want to test is if the text entered in the text field is equal to "Admin":

```
if (textField.getText().equals("Admin"))
```

Your code has other problems:

- using absolute coordinates instead of using a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- adding elements to the frame dynamically instead of adding them from the start and simply making them visible when needed. Adding is needed, but then the GUI needs to be revalidated.

Comment: thank you! Also, I guess I must have forgotten the textField_1 to check, now that I do know how to get the text from that box and then check. That should make it a lot easier for me. Also, with the layout manager it restricted me from having my buttons aligned like I pleased in a sort of 2 or 3 column lists with each having a bit of space in between. I will try and re-make it for a while (into one with a manager), but I am going to get this finished because I have a few friends eager to test it. :) Thanks again.